# Spring batch: composite tasklet?

Tags: spring-batch

I want to make composite tasklet class that can be composed from several tasklets.

Like this:

```
public class FinishingComposableTasklet implements Tasklet {

  private List<Tasklet> tasklets;

  public FinishingComposableTasklet(List<Tasklet> tasklets) {
    this.tasklets = tasklets;
  }

  @Override
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    for (Tasklet tasklet : tasklets) {
      tasklet.execute(contribution, chunkContext);
    }
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  }
}
```

I have a gut feeling that this is actually not correct:

1. I need somehow aggregate results from subtasklet's
2. If I need to aggregate them - it's probably not correct to return `FINISHED` 
   then
3. This class doesn't exist in standard spring batch classes for a reason

My question is - how should I compose smaller parts of my logic into one Step/Tasklet/Callable ?

If I will create such composite - will this break restart-ability of my job?

Comment: Do you need a composite tasklet class or job that consists of several tasklets? You can define that job in xml.

Comment: I know that I can define this as a steps. But then my definition will be pretty big and I am not sure that for every small thing I have to create separate step.

Comment: If you use springbatch java-api builder to add your taskletsteps to the job, it would be a one-liner for every tasklet. you also need one line to add your tasklet to your list of tasklets.